# Django framework with websocket

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

Iam working in django 2 with websockets inorder to pass the response to and fro a game server.Can anyone suggest the method or the correct flow for complete the communiction task between server and django through websockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is already set up in django then django-channels would make sense. Websocket consumers in django channels have full access to your django ORM and your other views in django can issue messages (over channel groups) that can be used to inform the open websocket connections of changes they need to stream to the user.

Comment: My server is in Clojure environment. And server is currently sending some datas. Will it be possible to communicate using django channels? If it is yes, can you please recommend some best blogs?  @Matthaus Woolard

Comment: talking to channels from outside of a python will require either hitting a python api (or script) or guessing the channel name in rabbitmq (I would not suggest this second option).

I haven't seen much documentation on linking between non python servers and channels servers.